# How does return statement with assignment work for calculating Fibonacci number

Tags: javascript

To understand the below Fibonacci calculator, I wonder how the following return statement with assignment works:

```js
let a = 0;
function foo (b) { 
  if (b === 20) return 1; 
  else return a = foo(b+1) + foo(b+1);
}
```

Which gives the following results:

```js
foo(15)
>> 32
a
>> 32
foo(18)
>> 4
a
>> 4
foo(19)
>> 2
a
>> 2
foo(10)
>> 1024
a
>> 1024
```

What is the exact behaviour of the assignment, and why do the values of a become multiples of 2?

This can possibly also explain why this works for calculating Fibonacci:

```js
const fib = (n, dp) => {
  dp = dp || {};
  if (dp[n]) return dp[n];
  if (n === 1) return 1;
  if (n === 0) return 0;
  return dp[n] = fib(n - 1, dp) + fib(n - 2, dp);
};
```

Comment: Your first bit of code *isn't* a Fibonacci calculator. It's clearly generating powers of two.

Comment: The code you have posted doesn't look correct if you are trying to produce fibonacci numbers

Comment: @epascarello I googled it, the definition was "recursion: see recursion."

Comment: "*To understand the below Fibonacci calculator, I wonder how the following return statement with assignment works:*" the two parts of this sentence are completely unrelated to one another. The assignment is not at all relevant to recursion or Fibonacci. The return value of assignment is just the assigned value `console.log(x = 42)` will log `42`.

Comment: Well, he has a Fibonacci calculator and it uses this "returned assignment", so he wants to know how that works so that he can understand how this particular Fibonacci number generator works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`return a = foo(b+1) + foo(b+1)` is a *return statement*. On the right-hand side of `return` here is an *assignment expression* (`a = foo(b+1) + foo(b+1)`).

The value of an assignment expression `identifer = right-hand-side-expression` is the result of evaluating the right-hand side expression, here: `foo(b+1) + foo(b+1)`.

So we can now describe what is happening: `foo(b+1) + foo(b+1)` is evaluated first and results in a value. This value is assigned to `a` using the assignment operator `=`. The result of this expression is then also returned.

Why the code is doing this, I do not know. It might be for convenient inspection while debugging the code.

Your first function recursively calculates powers of two because the value of each recursive step is the value of the previous recursive step added to the value of itself, which is equivalent to the value of the previous recursive step multiplied by two (ie. 2<sup>n+1</sup>), with a base case value of 1 (which is 2<sup>0</sup>); and the powers of two is a sequence showing how 2<sup>n</sup> varies as `n` is incremented one by one from zero.

A visualization of the call stack is shown below:

```js
function foo (b = 0) { 
  if (b === 4) 
      return 1
  else 
      return foo(b+1) + foo(b+1) // 16
}
console.log(foo())

// Building the stack:

// b | return
// --------------------
// 4 | 1
// 3 | foo(4) + foo(4)
// 2 | foo(3) + foo(3)
// 1 | foo(2) + foo(2)
// 0 | foo(1) + foo(1)   <--- start here

// Unwinding the stack:

// b | return
// ---------------------
// 4 | 1                 <--- start here
// 3 | 1 + 1   
// 2 | 2 + 2
// 1 | 4 + 4
// 0 | 8 + 8 // 16
```

Comment: But if you look at the results, that's not what it does? `foo(10)` returns 1 (since the stop condition `if (b === 20) return 1`, so I expect `foo(10) + foo(10) = 2`, but it returns, oh wait, I am calculating the recursion wrong 